# changing the font size in bootstrap modal message body

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code in order to show a modal window.
But i need to change the font size of text.
How can i do this?

```
var modal = $('#myModal');
modal.find('.modal-body p').html('I need this text in one line. <br/>And this text in another line');
$("#myModal").modal();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: changing the font size can be done via css, `font-size: 20px`

Comment: `modal.find('.modal-body p').html('I need this text in one line. <br/>And this text in another line').css("fontSize", "10px")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why don't you try adding CSS Class to the tag.

*Add this in your CSS file:*

```
.small-font{
      font-size: small;
  }
```

*and in code:*

```
var modal = $('#myModal');
modal.find('.modal-body p').html('<p class="small-font">I need this text in one line. <br/>And this text in another line<p>');
$("#myModal").modal();
```

**OR** you can use `<small>` tag around your text, like:

```
<small>I need this text in one line. <br/>And this text in another line</small>
```